# Render partial based on selection field value inside a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

In Rails 7 app I need to render partial with fields specific to a workflow when a new value is selected. What would be the best way of doing this? I have feeling that it's possible just with the use of turbo frame, without stimulus or turbo streams.

```
<%= form_with(model: @post, url: posts_path) do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :workflow %>
  <%= form.select :workflow, options_for_select(@workflow_options) %>

  <% if @role.workflow.present? %>
    <%= render partial: "#{@role.workflow}_properties", locals: { properties: @role[:workflow_properties] } %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit "Create Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with three solutions. I made these copy-pasteable to work on any page. `onchange` can be replaced with simple stimulus controller or just an event listener and some data attributes.

#### Set turbo frame `src`

Set a new turbo frame url with needed params:

```rb
<%= form_with url: request.path do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :workflow, ["basic", "advanced"], {prompt: true},
    onchange: "workflow_frame.src=`${location.href}?workflow=${this.value}`" %> <br>

  <%= turbo_frame_tag :workflow_frame do %>
    TODO: render "<%= ['workflow', params[:workflow].presence].compact.join('_') %>"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Use another submit button

Submit the form to do something other than create/update:

```rb
<%= form_with url: request.path do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :workflow, ["basic", "advanced"], {prompt: true} %>
  <%= f.submit "next", formaction: request.path, formmethod: :get,
    data: {turbo_frame: :workflow_frame_two} %> <br>

  <%= turbo_frame_tag :workflow_frame_two do %>
    TODO: render "<%= ['workflow', params[:workflow].presence].compact.join('_') %>"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and you can auto-click the "next" button:

```rb
<%= form_with url: request.path do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :workflow, ["basic", "advanced"], {prompt: true},
    onchange: "update_workflow_frame.click()" %> <br>
  <%= f.submit "next", id: "update_workflow_frame", formaction: request.path, formmethod: :get,
    data: {turbo_frame: :workflow_frame_two}, style: "display:none!important" %>

  <%= turbo_frame_tag :workflow_frame_two do %>
    TODO: render "<%= ['workflow', params[:workflow].presence].compact.join('_') %>"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### Use links (no javascript)

Use links instead of a select field to trigger turbo frame navigation:

```rb
<% current_workflow = ->(str) { str.eql?(params[:workflow]) } %>
<%= form_with url: request.path do |f| %>
  <%= turbo_frame_tag :workflow_frame_three do %>
    <%= link_to "basic",    request.path + "?workflow=basic",    class: {selected: current_workflow.("basic") } %> <br>
    <%= link_to "advanced", request.path + "?workflow=advanced", class: {selected: current_workflow.("advanced") } %> <br>
    <%= f.hidden_field :workflow, value: params[:workflow] %>

    TODO: render "<%= ['workflow', params[:workflow].presence].compact.join('_') %>"
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<style>.selected{font-weight: bold}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you might approach the problem with stimulus.js.

The form (haml notation):

```
= form_for @post, html: {'data-controller'=>'form'} do |f|

  = f.label :workflow 
  = f.select :workflow, options_for_select(@workflow_options), {}, 'data-action'=>'change->form#fetch_dynamic', 'data-form-target'=>'formSelect', id: 'form_select'
  %div{'data-form-target'=>'dynamicForm'}
    = f.label :information, "Enter your information"
    = f.text_field :information
  %br
  = f.submit "Create Post"
```

The div element will be changed-out with other versions when the user makes different selections of the select box options.

The stimulus controller looks like this:

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import { FetchRequest } from '@rails/request.js'


export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "formSelect", "dynamicForm" ]

  async fetch_dynamic() {
    let selection = this.formSelectTarget.value
    const request = new FetchRequest('get', '/posts/new', { query: {type: selection}})
    const response = await request.perform()
    if (response.ok) {
      const form = await response.text
      const dynamic_form = this.dynamicFormTarget
      dynamic_form.innerHTML=form
    }
  }
}
```

I use rails' request.js to make the xhr request. The controller responds with the requested form partial:

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @workflow_options = %i[foo bar baz qux] # different form partials
    requested_form = params[:type] # type of form partial specified in a query parameter
    if requested_form
      render partial: "#{requested_form}_form", layout: false
      return
    end
  end

end
```

A form partial is just a snippet of html (haml):

```rb
#_baz_form.html.haml

= label :post, :information, "Enter your baz information"
= text_field :post, :information
```