# Reloading a Turbo Frame without Stimulus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

https://web-crunch.com/posts/turbo-charged-real-time-search-ruby-on-rails-7

I am following this tutorial to include Turbo into our app. However we would prefer not to have to install the stimulus gem since it appears to add a lot of KB to the asset pipeline. Is there a way to implement the same behavior with plain Javascript? I.e. reloading only the Turbo frame on an "input" event.

The relevant code from the tutorial:

Form that updates a Turbo Frame:

```
<%= form_with(url: bands_path, method: :get, data: {turbo_frame: "bands"}) do |form| %>

  <%= form.label :query, "Search by band name:", class: "block mb-2" %>
  <div class="flex space-x-3">
    <%= form.text_field :query, class: "py-3 px-4 rounded border ring-0 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-orange-100 focus:shadow-none focus:border-orange-500 focus:outline-none" %>

    <%= form.submit 'Search', class: "px-4 py-3 font-medium
  bg-orange-300 text-neutal-900 rounded flex items-center cursor-pointer hover:bg-orange-400 focus:ring-4 ring-0 focus:ring-orange-100" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Turbo frame partial:

```
<!-- app/views/bands/_bands.html.erb-->
<%= turbo_frame_tag "bands" do %>
  <%= render bands %>
<% end >
```

Stimulus controller:

```
// application/javascript/controllers/search_form_controller.js

import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="search-form"
export default class extends Controller {
  search() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.element.requestSubmit()
    }, 200)
  }
}
```

What we have attempted is to set the src parameter of the turbo-frame to a new search on input, but this doesn't appear to generate a new turbo_frame_request:

```
<%= form.text_field :query, oninput: "bands.src=`${location.href}?query=${this.value}`" %>
```

Comment: Yes. https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events

Comment: also your solution should work, because i've tried it and also i've done that before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691597/207090. maybe you have some other issue that causing frame not to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the same thing that the stimulus controller does - submit the form:

```rb
<%= form_with url: request.path, method: :get, data: {turbo_frame: :bands} do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :q, oninput: "search(event)" %>
<% end %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag :bands, data: {turbo_action:  :advance} do %>
  <%= params[:q] %>
<% end %>

<script charset="utf-8">
  function search(event) {
    event.target.closest("form").requestSubmit()
  }
</script>
```

Also Stimulus is 12kb compressed and you can get it from a CDN, you're not saving any space by avoiding it: *https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/stimulus*.